# Is there a way to prove Compact $\Leftarrow$ Closed and Bounded in a finite dimensional normed space WITHOUT this famous Lemma?

Tags: reference-request, normed-spaces, compactness

**Context.** It is well known that in a finite dimensional normed space $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$, a subset $M \subset X$ is said to be compact **iff** $M$ is closed and bounded.

The $(\Rightarrow)$ is pretty much straightforward, since we know that a compact subset of a metric space is closed and bounded (and a (finite dimensional) normed space is a metric space with the metric induced by the norm).

On the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication: with some easy search, one can find several proofs of this (even on YouTube, or here, really). But all of these have one thing in common: They use the following auxiliary *Lemma.*

**Lemma.** Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a linearly independent set of vectors in a normed space $X$ (of any dimension). Then there is a number $c>0$ such that for every choice of scalar $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ we have
$$ \| \alpha_1x_1 + \dots + \alpha_nx_n\| \leqslant c(|\alpha_1| + \dots + |\alpha_n|).$$
And I was wondering: Certainly there must be a way to prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication **without** using the *Lemma* above, but I can't find no proof like this *online*.

Basically I am looking for some references (or the proof itself) of this implication **without** using the *Lemma* mentioned above.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why? It's a very simple lemma. Unless I'm mistaken, you can just take $c$ to be $\max(\|x_i\|;i=1,2,\cdots,n)$

Comment: I know it is a simple *lemma* : I am just curious - there should be a way to prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication with some results like equivalence of norms or the fact that there exists a linear and topological isomorphism between $\Bbb K^n$ and $X$, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TlDr; just use Heine-Borel for $\Bbb R^n$, after appealing to the linear homeomorphism $X\cong\Bbb R^n$.

If you want a more birds-eye approach, there is a general Heine-Borel-Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. All three conditions are equivalent:
>
> - $X$ is topologically compact
> - $X$ is sequentially compact
> - $X$ is complete and totally bounded

Our finite dimensional vector space $X$ is, if you take the ground field to be $\Bbb R$ (say), complete (that's because $\Bbb R^n$ is, if you like). Any closed subset thereof is also complete.

All you need to do is determine that a bounded subset $C$ of $X$ is also totally bounded, meaning:

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists finitely many points $(x_n)_{n=1}^m$ of $C$ and balls $B(x_n,\epsilon)$ which cover $C$ in their union.

This is like a special case of compactness: such covers are called $\epsilon$-nets.

Let's use the linear-and-topological isomorphism $X\cong\Bbb R^n$. The bounded subset $C$ is mapped to an isomorph $C'\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ which is also bounded. We must verify that $C'$ is totally bounded; this more-or-less follows from the Pythagorean identity:

> Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{N}<\epsilon$. $C'$ is contained within some box $[-M,M]^n$, where $M>0$ is a constant integer. This box allows a partition into lattice points of the form $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ where each coordinate has $Nx_i\in\Bbb Z\cap[-M,M]$. We can place, at every such lattice point $x$, a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$. Note that the cube: $$\{(y_1,\cdots,y_n)\in[-M,M]^n:|y-x_i|\le1/N\}$$Is completely covered by $B(x,\epsilon)$ by choice of $N$. Taking the union of the $B(x,\epsilon)$ over all lattice points $x$, we have a cover of $[-M,M]$ and thus a cover of $C'$ via a finite $\epsilon$-net, as desired.

So every bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is totally bounded, every bounded subset of $X$ is totally bounded (it is an isomorphism invariant). We could have done the same proof within $X$ after first fixing an orthonormal basis too.

Every closed, bounded subset of $X$ is then complete and totally bounded hence compact by the main theorem. Really, by the isomorphism, it suffices to check the Heine-Borel theorem for subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ - maybe you know a proof for that already.

Comment: How would write something more formal using only the isomorphism and the usual Heine-Borel Theorem for $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @roro *more* formal? I think "my" argument is already formal - it is textbook, after all. But the linear homeomorphism $\Gamma:X\to\Bbb R^n$ easily carries closed sets to closed sets (homeomorphism) and bounded sets to bounded sets (linear continuous) thus $C\subseteq X$ is closed and bounded iff. $\Gamma(C)$ is closed and bounded iff. $\Gamma(C)$ is compact (Heine-Borel, weak $\Bbb R^n$ version) iff. ($\Gamma$ is a homeomorphism) $C$ is compact.

Comment: You're (indeed) right - your arguments are very clear. I am just that dumb... Anyway: I understand that a linear homeomorphism maps closed sets to closed sets and bounded sets to bounded sets (thus, maps closed and bounded sets to closed and bounded sets). What I am not understanding is: $\Gamma(C)$ is compact **iff.** $C$ is compact. Is this also a property from homeomorphisms?

Comment: @roro Yes. To see this in pure generality, let $X,Y$ be any two topological spaces and $\Gamma:X\cong Y$ a homeomorphism. Fix $C\subseteq X$. As $\Gamma$ is continuous, $\Gamma(C)$ is compact when $C$ is compact. As $\Gamma^{-1}$ is continuous, $\Gamma^{-1}(\Gamma(C))=C$ is compact whenever $\Gamma(C)$ is compact. Together, $C$ is compact iff. $\Gamma(C)$ is. To see continuous functions map compact subsets to compact subsets, any open cover of $\Gamma(C)$ pullsback (by continuity) to an open cover of $C$, which reduces to a finite subcover. This reflects to a finite subcover of $\Gamma(C)$!

Comment: Oh wow! Great explanation. I am sorry about my **rusty** topological knowledges!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Can you explain more clearly why an homeomorphism maps bounded sets to bounded sets?

Comment: @roro They don't, in general. Boundedness is a metric concept, not a topological concept. Consider e.g. the homeomorphism $x\mapsto1/x$ in $(0,1)\cong(1,\infty)$. But a linear continuous map is bounded, so we get this property

Comment: So basically **every** continuous linear map is bounded and thus every  **linear homeomorphism** maps bounded sets to bounded sets?

Comment: @roro Yup. Linear mappings are norm-continuous iff. they are bounded

Comment: Let me recap something: I am used to this definition: Let $T\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a operator between **normed spaces**. We say $T$ is bounded if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that, for all $x \in X$, $$ \|Tx\|_Y \leqslant c\|x\|_X. $$ Is this definition equivalent to saying that $T$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets?

Comment: @roro Yes. If this holds, then given a bounded $B$, say with $x\in B\implies\|x\|\le M$ for constant $M$, we have $\|Tx\|\le c\|x\|\le Mc$ for all $x\in B$. So $T(B)$ is bounded by $Mc$. Conversely if $T$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets, it in particular maps the unit sphere $S$ to a bounded set $TS$. Say $TS$ is bounded in norm by $c$. Then $\|x\|=1\implies\|Tx\|\le c$. For a general nonzero vector $x$, $\|T(x/\|x\|)\|\le c$ so: $$c\ge\|T(x/\|x\|)\|=\|(Tx)/\|x\|\|=\|Tx\|/\|x\|\implies c\|x\|\ge\|Tx\|$$As $x$ is arbitrary, $c$ is a uniform bound for $T$.

Comment: @roro As for continuous iff. bounded, this is well-known. Check first that a linear map is continuous iff. it is continuous at the origin. Then check that this is equivalent to $T$ being bounded (arbitrarily well) near the origin; then check that this is equivalent to $T$ being a bounded map.

Comment: Wow... this is better than my classes. Thank you for all your help (once again).

Comment: @roro You're very welcome