# Proving boundedness of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional normed space with norm $||\cdot||$. Show that $T : (E,||\cdot||) \rightarrow (\mathbb{K}^n,||\cdot||_\infty),$ given by $x = \sum_{I=1}^nx_ie_i \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is continuous.

My attempt: Let $B = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a base for $E$. Then for any $x = \sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i$ where $(x_i)_{I=1}^n \in \mathbb{K}^n$ we have the following: \begin{align*}||Tx||_\infty & = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|x_i|\\
& \leq \sum_{I=1}^n|x_i|\frac{||e_i||}{||e_i||}\\
& = \frac{1}{\sum_{I=1}^n||e_i||}\sum_{i=1}^n||x_ie_i||.\end{align*}But now I am stuck because I can't go from $\sum_{i=1}^n||x_ie_i||$ to $||\sum_{I=1}^nx_ie_i|| = ||x||$.

**Ps**.: I am not able to use the famous auxiliary lemma: that gives the following estimate $$c|\sum_{I=1}x_i| \leq ||x_1e_1 + \dots x_ne_n|| = ||x||.$$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Just to be clear, $T$ is the function that maps $x=\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i e_i$ to the vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb K^n$, is that right ? In particular, $\text{dim}(E) = \text{dim}(\mathbb K^n) = n$ ?

Comment: @StratosFair Yes, T is indeed that function and both dimensions are $n$. I also saw something related with compactness but I was wondering if it was possible to do it directly just using the definition of boundedness or even continuity.

Comment: @mnp It's probably not possible to prove this without compactness because the result does not hold if $n$ is infinite.

Comment: @Mason but our case is restricted to finite $n$. In this situation, E must be finite dimensional. Does it change something? And why is the result false for infinite n?

Comment: Essentially because the topology is complicated @mnp The topology of finite dimensional linear spaces is easy, everything works out nicely. Infinite dimensions give room for wandering sequences that don't accumulate (e.g.) and other pathologies

Comment: This is the [second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4574886/815585) I've seen recently that eschews this 'famous lemma' (which is totally trivial by the way!). I don't see why... you might like my final bullet point in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574625/815585) to see that any linear function out of a finite dimensional space is continuous

Comment: @FShrike, I will check it out! Thank you for the reference!!

Comment: No problem. Seriously though - the 'lemma' you refuse to use makes the problem more or less a one-liner (!) - why exclude its use?

Comment: @FShrike Precisely, that's how it's done in Kreysig! But I was wondering how to prove the same stuff without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $E$ and $F$ are normed spaces with $n = \dim E < +\infty$ then every linear operator $S:E\to F$ is continuous. Indeed, if $$x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i$$
where $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis for $E$, then
$$\lVert Sx \rVert_F=\left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^nx_iSe_i\right\rVert_F \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\lVert Se_i\rVert_F\leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert Se_i\rVert_F^2\right)^{1/2}$$

In a finite-dimensional space, all norms are equivalent (this can be proven with or without the "famous" lemma) so continuity is guaranteed.

Comment: I see, you used Holder's Inequality to get the $||.||_2$ norm on $x \in X$ right? and $C = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert Se_i\rVert_F^2\right)^{1/2} > 0$.

Comment: @mnp Yeah, exactly!